# How to plot a lemniscate on a surface

Tags: plotting

How do I plot a lemniscate:

```
ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2)^2 == 2*(x^2 - y^2), {x, -1.8, 
1.8}, {y, -0.63, 0.63}]
```

[image: lemniscate]

on the following surface:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}]
```

[image: paraboloid]

Answer (score 11):

The most convenient way is to start from the parametric equations of the lemniscate of Bernoulli, instead of insisting on the implicit equation. I can't be bothered to remember the precise parametric equations, but I do remember that the lemniscate is the [inverse curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCurve.html) of an equilateral hyperbola. Thus,

```
lem[t_] = TrigExpand[Sqrt[2] #/(#.#) &[{Sec[t], Tan[t]}]];
```

One can now do this:

```
Show[Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}], 
     ParametricPlot3D[Append[lem[t], Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2] @@ lem[t]],
                      {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], Orange}]]
```

[image: lemniscate embedded in a paraboloid]

---

If one insists on using `ContourPlot[]`, you can extract the `Line[]` objects and manipulate them like so:

```
lem = Cases[Normal[ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2)^2 == 2*(x^2 - y^2),
                               {x, -1.8, 1.8}, {y, -0.63, 0.63}]], 
            Line[l_] :> Line[Append[#, Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2] @@ #] & /@ l], ∞];

Show[Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}], 
     Graphics3D[{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], Orange], lem}]]
```

Answer (score 6):

I may have picked wrong surface (but can be adapted). Just fun with another parametrization:

```
l[s_] := {(4 + 3 Sqrt[2] + (4 - 3 Sqrt[2]) s^4)/(
  3 + 2 Sqrt[2] + 6 s^2 + (3 - 2 Sqrt[2]) s^4), 
  Sqrt[2] s (1/(1 + s^2) + 1/(-3 - 2 Sqrt[2] + (-3 + 2 Sqrt[2]) s^2))}
lp[s_] := Join[l[s], {0}]
f[s_] := Module[{p = l[s]},
  {#1, #2, #1^2 + #2^2} & @@ p
  ]
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{f[t], lp[t]}, {t, -400, 400}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{-2.6, 2.6}, {-2.6, 2.6}, {0, 3}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2.6, 2.6}, {y, -2.6, 2.6}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Encoding the equation in a `MeshFunctions` definition and setting `Mesh->{{0}}`is my preferred method:

```
Plot3D[
   x^2 + y^2, {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
   MeshFunctions -> ((#1^2 + #2^2)^2 - 2*(#1^2 - #2^2) &), 
   Mesh -> {{0}}
]
```

[image]